# Flash builder 4.0 hide text if string is empty mxml

Tags: flash-builder, mxml

What to do to hide **Office manager:** if **{manager}** is empty?

```
<mx:Text id="lblManager" text="Office manager: {manager}" width="220" height="20"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You may also test if "manager" is null:

```
<mx:Text id="lblManager" visible="{manager.length > 0}" text="Office manager: {manager}" width="220" height="20"/>
```